# What is the difference between register_buffer() and parameter.detach() in PyTorch?

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, transformer, machine-translation

I am writing a `PositionalEmbedding()` module which is an implementation based on "[Attention Is All You Need](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/7181-attention-is-all-you-need.pdf)" using PyTorch. According to the paper, there should be no learnable attribute in the module `PositionalEmbedding()`.

The initialization of the Embedding weights is as follows:

```
    import math
    import torch
    
    class TrigonometricPositionalEmbedding(torch.nn.Module):
        def __init__(self, embedding_number, dimension, padding_idx):
            position = torch.arange(0, embedding_number).unsqueeze(1)
            sin_multiplicator = torch.exp(-(math.log(10000) / dimension) * 2 * torch.arange(0, dimension, 2))
            cos_multiplicator = torch.exp(-(math.log(10000) / dimension) * 2 * torch.arange(1, dimension, 2))
            sin_weight = torch.sin(position * sin_multiplicator)
            cos_weight = torch.cos(position * cos_multiplicator)
    
            weight = torch.zeros(embedding_number, dimension)
            weight[:, 0::2] = sin_weight
            weight[:, 1::2] = cos_weight
```

Next up, because the `weight` in the module should not be learnable, `detach()` the `weight` came into my mind. I think it may not be the most elegant way, so I made a further investigation. I found that there are two kinds of implementation method like what [OpenNMT](https://github.com/OpenNMT/OpenNMT-py/blob/master/onmt/modules/embeddings.py#L34) and [FAIRSeq](https://github.com/pytorch/fairseq/blob/master/fairseq/modules/sinusoidal_positional_embedding.py#L104) have done respectively.

I follow the method of **OpenNMT** and my implementation is as follows:

```
    class TrigonometricPositionalEmbedding(torch.nn.Module):
        def __init__(self, embedding_number, dimension, padding_idx):
            ...
            weight[:, 1::2] = cos_weight
            self.register_buffer('weight', weight)
    
        def forward(self, position):
            torch.index_select(self.weight, 0, position)
```

I follow the method of **FAIRSeq** and my implementation is as follows:

```
    class TrigonometricPositionalEmbedding(torch.nn.Module):
        def __init__(self, embedding_number, dimension, padding_idx):
            ...
            weight[:, 1::2] = cos_weight
            self.weight = weight
    
        def forward(self, position):
            torch.index_select(self.weight, 0, position).detach()
```

So I am curious about the difference between the two method, or what is the difference between **registered buffer** and **detached parameter**?

(The question was also posted in [PyTorch Forums](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/what-is-the-difference-between-register-buffer-and-parameter-detach-in-pytorch/87163) but no answer yet.)